# url scheme in game maker studio(yoyo games) for android?

Tags: android, url-scheme, game-maker

How can i make url scheme in Game maker Studio (Yoyogames) for android?

I've seen in some application like Whatsapp app have a url scheme that when the user surf to a " whatsapp://send?text=mytext " site, it opens the Whatsapp app with a given text.

so i want to make like that.if user enter my url scheme to open the game with a given text.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
//pass the URL string as argument0 to this script to open it in default browser
url_open_ext(argument0, '_blank')
```

Comment: execute_shell This code is does not working in game maker studio.

Comment: @AjayHQRathva I've updated it to work correctly; make sure argument0 is a string.